# function like macro curly braces or do..while

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do-While and if-else statements in C/C++ macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I have the following function-like macro and just wondering what is the preferred usage when using across multiple lines. It it better to use curly braces or do..while(0) loop.

Normally I use a do..while(0) for everything. But I have seen some projects where they just use the curly braces, and I am not sure which one would be better.

do..while

```
#define DSO_ERROR(msg, res_handle_module, mem_pool, size)   do {        \
        char *dso_error = apr_palloc((apr_pool_t*)mem_pool, size);      \
        apr_dso_error((apr_dso_handle_t*)res_handle_module, (char*)dso_error, (apr_size_t)size); \
        LOG_ERR("%s dso error %s", (char*)msg, dso_error);              \
        goto dso_failure;                                               \
    } while(0);
```

curly braces

```
#define DSO_ERROR(msg, res_handle_module, mem_pool, size) {             \
        char *dso_error = apr_palloc((apr_pool_t*)mem_pool, size);      \
        apr_dso_error((apr_dso_handle_t*)res_handle_module, (char*)dso_error, (apr_size_t)size); \
        LOG_ERR("%s dso error %s", (char*)msg, dso_error);              \
        goto dso_failure;                                               \
    }
```

The only difference is that a semi-colon will be preset on the do..while loop and not on the curly braces.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Adding the semicolon to the end of the `do { ... } while (0)` defeats the purpose of using `do { ... } while (0)` in the first place.  The disadvantage of the braces-only version is that you cannot write `if (something) DSO_ERROR(...); else { ... }` because the semicolon is a null statement after the `if` and the `else` is a syntax error.  With the corrected version of `do { ... } while (0)`, the `if` / `else` notation works as you'd expect if the macro were actually a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The curly brace version will break usage like this:

```
if( foo )
  DSO_ERROR("Foo occured!", my_module, the_pool, 4711);
else
  printf("All is well, there is no foo\n");
```

which is the very reason for the `do ... while(0)` construct. So that seems worth avoiding.

Comment: As written by OP, the do...while(0) version will also break because it has an extra semicolon at the end. The right way to write the do...while(0) is without the semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

you will have a problem with this code:

```
if (one) 
  DSO_ERROR("one", ...);
else
  DSO_ERROR("two", ...);
```

so if you use the do-while-Macro WITHOUT the semicolon, you would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you do *not* have the semicolon on the `do { ... } while (0)` in the macro.

The reason you have `do { ... } while (0)` for the macro, is that then you can use the macro in the source and add a semicolon without there being an extra empty statement. This is mostly for historical reasons I guess, as having empty statements (i.e. just semicolons without any statements) doesn't do anything in many cases.

Comment: "...doesn't do anything" except dangling else-problem